# Blocking File and Printer Sharing on Windows domain controller

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain-controller

I have a Windows 2012 R2 domain controller that doesn't need any Filter and Printer sharing ports open, so in an attempt to harden the server I've tried disabling the rules in the "File and Printer Sharing" group.

However, every time I reboot, the rules keep getting enabled. I've tried removing it everywhere, include the Windows Firewall "Allow features" settings as well on the NIC connection settings. But it keeps getting enabled when I reboot.

Short of writing a script to disable the rules and adding it to the scheduled tasks, how do I get the disabled rules to stay disabled?

Thanks.

**Update:**
Sorry, I should have been clearer. I'm only using this server for running Exchange, no other clients will be connecting to the domain controller for authentication. I realize it's not a recommended configuration (running it on the domain controller), but it's only for a few users. It's sitting facing the internet, and I'd like to only allow port 25 and 443 (for owa and rpc over http).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that disabling File Sharing on a Domain Controller is going to render ADDS unusable.

Comment: @joeqwerty I'll vote for that. How are clients going to get Sysvol and Netlogon?

Comment: @Ryan - exactly. :)

Answer (score 1):

Blocking File and Printer Sharing will break Active Directory Domain Services. If you review the [Active Directory and Active Directory Domain Services Port Requirements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) you'll notice that following ports need to be open. The reason the rules get re-enabled is when you install Roles that require certain services and their ports to be open Windows will automatically enable those rules.

- UDP 137, File and Printer Sharing (NB-Datagram-In)
- UDP 138, File and Printer Sharing (NB-Name-In)
- TCP 139, File and Printer Sharing (NB-Session-In)
- TCP 445, File and Printer Sharing (SMB-In)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I'm only using this server for running Exchange, no other clients will be connecting to the domain controller for authentication. I realize it's not a recommended configuration (running it on the domain controller), but it's only for a few users. It's sitting facing the internet, and I'd like to only allow port 25 and 443 (for owa and rpc over http).

Comment: Wait - you are running Exchange on a Domain Controller that is internet facing? That sounds like a terrible idea for reasons too numerous to mention. Since you are using Server 2012, install Hyper-V and then install Exchange in one VM and your Domain Controller in the other.

Comment: Running two separate instances of Windows ties up quite a lot of resources in terms of RAM/disk space. I understand that it's not a recommended configuration, but based on my understanding it is a supported configuration. If every port is blocked except 443 and 25, then is it that bad?

Comment: Yes. It's a bad idea. Especially since there are other substantially better options available to you. If you want to proceed you will need another firewall between your upstream connection and your Exchange Server/Domain Controller because I can't think of way to prevent Windows from automatically enabling those rules.

Comment: What are the substantially better options, given I don't want to waste resources running 2 separate instances of Windows?